# Detener un comando lanzado por powershell

Tags: powershell

Hace unos días lancé un comando para ir monitorizando que procesos consumían más rendimiento en un equipo y que lo vaya pasando a un .log cada 60 segundos. Hasta ahí muy bien y funcionando, pero el problema es que no se como detenerlo. Según el Resource Monitor lo está utilizando el proceso system y no puedo detenerlo. ¿Que puedo hacer? Muchas gracias de antemano.

El comando que lancé es este:

```
While(1) {ps | sort -des ws | select -f 15 | ft -a; | Out-File Monitorizado.log; sleep 60;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se podría parar sobre el powershell lanzado con CTRL + C o si está en background se podría para el proceso por ejemplo mediante los siguientes comandos:

```
 get-process powershell |select -expand id

 stop-process -id ID_DEVUELTO -confirm -passthru
```

Comment: Es en background. Estos comandos que me cuentas me hacen surgir un problema y es que me devuelven tres procesos de Powershell y no se cual es el que quiero detener. ¿Hay alguna manera de saber que está haciendo cada uno?

Comment: ¿Con el start time del comando Get-Process -ID PROCESS_ID | Select-Object * te valdría?

Comment: O mejor todavía recuperar el id del proceso $app = start-process powershell -argument "C:\Scripts\myscript.ps1 Argument"
se guardar el $app.Id en un archivo y asi ya sabemos cual es